# Chrome Extension - Use Another HTML Source

Tags: google-chrome

I'm creating a extension and here is what I want to do.

I have site "www.aaa.com" and the extension I developed can read and navigate DOM element by javascript. However, when I click the extension icon, I'd like get and read the HTML source from "www.bbb.com".

The current page is "www.aaa.com", but want to get the source of "www.bbb.com" in the current page.

How can I do this??

Comment: Sorry, but if you have to ask "how can I do this", it's not you who's creating the extension, you're asking for someone else to do it for you. Which part specifically do you not know how to make?

Comment: @Juhana I don't know what your point is. I'm working on developing an extension which needs to get HTML source of another webpage.